# Raspberry pi 3 model b doesn't boot

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, boot-issues, osmc

I recently bought a new pi 3 from a merchant on a platform like ebay. It came as a combo with power supply 2.5A, the board itself, heatsinks and the white and red enclosure box. Everything looks fine and original, and the guy had quite a decent reputation so I am assuming (without outlying) that the hardware is fine.

I have though had no success in booting it. I want to install osmc, so I downloaded the latest image, which I have tried to write to microSD with osmc's installer.

I have tried with 3 different 4Gb SD cards and one 16GB one. These are all a few years old, the latter had problems with mounting on linux, but the other 4GB ones I have been able to copy pictures to the HD before flashing it to use for osmc. All these cards have been working fine in a Nikon digital camera, but haven't been used for maybe 2 years now.

The osmc installer completes fine and reports success.

Nevertheless, with all cards, the result has been the same : red LED goes on, but the green flashes **2 times **, not very fast, the first a bit longer than the second. Apart from that, no apparent activity,and the screen (through HDMI) shows nothing.

I must assume that there's a problem with the cards. Nevertheless I am a bit surprised by the issue that out of 4, not one worked.

Next attempt will be to buy a new sd card (8gb),but I wonder if someone can give any other comment on this.

Comment: [R-Pi Troubleshooting](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting)... Green LED blinks in a specific pattern... 2 flashes: The SD Card cannot be read.

Comment: Write a standard image from raspberrypi.org, e.g. Raspbian Lite (it may fit on a 4GB card).  You really need some certainty as to whether the Pi is functional or not.

Answer (score 0):

For the records, following @joan 's proposal in the comments (welcome to provide an answer so I can accept it if you like), I ended up downloading NOOBS on zip.

I followed this tutorial on how to properly format a SD Card on linux and install NOOBS:
http://qdosmsq.dunbar-it.co.uk/blog/2013/06/noobs-for-raspberry-pi/

And - tata!!! I now have LibreELEC running.

It may be that the SD card needed to be correctly formatted first, but I am not up for more experiments now and stick to LibreELEC, as I want to use the Pi as low-power music (media) center and thus KODI is my main need.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.